# Bitcoind address index

Tags: bitcoind, scantxoutset

Does anyone know some reliable Bitcoind fork which allows to use address index?
I know that there are 
 https://github.com/bitpay/bitcoin and
 https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/releases

But is seems that there are not supported any more.

What I really need, it is getting unspend outputs for any address (not for the wallet only), and it need to work fast(max 1-5s).

Answer (score 3):

The scantxoutset RPC in 0.17+ will do what you want, although unless you batch query several addresses at once it may be a bit slower than what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Have a look at Bitpays bitcore:
https://bitcore.io/guides</s>

Edit October 2018: this software is no longer reliable.

Comment: It seems to not be supported anymore. The last update is 0.12.1 version from last year...

Comment: I guess stopping at 0.12.1 was done intentionally. But not sure.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anyone use that software: it's unmaintained and unreliable.